# sql datetime cast error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime-format

I have a kind of date time format like this 'Mon Sep 26 18:30:24 UTC+0200 2016'. I need to insert into a table as date-time...Can anybody help me on this?

```
select convert(datetime,'Fri Jan 1 00:00:00 UTC+0100 1960')
```

> ERROR:Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from
>   character string.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: **culture specific** DateTime formats are something really bad. But **culture specific AND language dependant** formats are directly brought to us by the devil of messy data to cover us with never ending pain... I hope this question is related to convert the bad and dark into something clear, pure and bright :-)

Comment: I using MDSN SSMS

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? (NOT SSMS, but the actual SQL Server?)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      13.0.16000.28
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.14393

Comment: The server version doesn't matter. Dates have no format. They are binary values. Inserting text instead of a date value is a serious bug. It's actually *easier* to write a parameterized query and pass date values instead of trying to parse arbitrary strings. Why are you trying to insert text instead of a `datetime` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment (I'm using SSMS) I take, this is SQL Server.

You might try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(StringDate VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('Fri Jan 1 00:00:00 UTC+0100 1960'),('Mon Nov 28 12:30:00 UTC+0100 2016');

SELECT StringDate
      ,ToXml
      ,HundredAndNine
      ,CONVERT(DATETIME,HundredAndNine,109) AS Converted
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(StringDate,' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS Casted(ToXml)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ToXml.value('/x[2]','varchar(3)') + ' ' --part 2: The month
                 + ToXml.value('/x[3]','varchar(2)') + ' ' --part 3: The day
                 + ToXml.value('/x[6]','varchar(4)') + ' ' --part 6: The year
                 + ToXml.value('/x[4]','varchar(8)') --part 4: The time
                 ) AS DateTimeFormat(HundredAndNine)
```

As your format is not compatible to any of the supported formats ([find details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)), we have to use string methods to re-sort your constructing parts.

My code uses a trick to **split** the string at the blanks. Each blank is replaced by `</x><x>`. One `<x>` at the beginning and a `</x>` at the end allows to address each part as one element within an XML.

```
<x>Fri</x>
<x>Jan</x>
<x>1</x>
<x>00:00:00</x>
<x>UTC+0100</x>
<x>1960</x>
```

I read and re-concatenate the parts to fit into pattern `109`. The rest is trivial...

### UPDATE: A function for this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CovertStrangeFormatToDateTime(@StringDate VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
RETURN
(
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,HundredAndNine,109) AS Converted
    FROM 
    (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@StringDate,' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS Casted(ToXml)
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT ToXml.value('/x[2]','varchar(3)') + ' ' --part 2: The month
                     + ToXml.value('/x[3]','varchar(2)') + ' ' --part 3: The day
                     + ToXml.value('/x[6]','varchar(4)') + ' ' --part 6: The year
                     + ToXml.value('/x[4]','varchar(8)') --part 4: The time
                     ) AS DateTimeFormat(HundredAndNine)
)
END
GO
```

And you call it simply as this:

```
SELECT dbo.CovertStrangeFormatToDateTime('Fri Jan 1 00:00:00 UTC+0100 1960');
```

Comment: The final results is fine thank, but I need to use this part of code inside of an Insert query, and I have a lot of datetimes like this. 
I have no idea hove to create the query :(

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure to read this first: [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.130).aspx)

I think it's better to use date format "127".

```
CONVERT(varchar(50), DateValueField, 127)
```

or if you think other date format suits you better, then change the "127" into your new format code.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: As far as I got this, the problem is, that the *real-world* data is in the given format and OP has to convert this...

Comment: It's better to use **no** format, and pass datetime values as datetime values, as a parameter value. Storing or passing dates as text harms performance and allows conversion errors to slip in

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are rigth - for sure! - that is was best to avoid such formats at all...  But we don't know the OP's acutal issue. Quite often one has to deal with interface data, legacy tools or third party components. I hope, this question is an attempt to **repair** this (see my comment above...)